# preferred method of iteration with getattr() and np arrays

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

`__init__(self):`

`class` parse csv file with `pandas`

convert the `DataFrame` into a `np.array(df)`

iterate `array`:

`try:`

`array.astype(float)`

`append` the key to a list of `class` keys

`except ValueError:` and assume the data is not numeric.

```py
with open(file.txt) as f:
        df = pd.read_csv(f, sep=r'\\s*|,|\t', engine='python',
                         header=0, names=names, index_col=0).iloc[:, :-1]
        
        dfa = np.array(df)

        for i, key in enumerate(df,index):
            try:
                a = dfa[i].astype(float)
                setattr(self.models, key, a)
                self.models.keys.append(key)

            except ValueError:
                pass
```

with 2 different instance I can compare the numeric data for differences/changes over time.

```py
   idx = int(timeD / 3600)
   cM = self.as_matrix(np.s_[:-idx])
   # slice previousMatrix head by idx offset
   xM = x.as_matrix(np.s_[idx:])
```

my question is which of/or is there a more preferred method for iter for the two methods shown below.

```py
    def as_matrix(self, i=None):
        return np.array(
            list(map(lambda k: getattr(self.models, k)[i], self.models.keys)))
```

```py
    def as_matrix(self, i=None):
        return np.array(
            [getattr(self.models, k)[i] for k in self.models.keys])
```

Comment: The second seems more idiomatic for python

Comment: Are you asking is list comprehensions are more idiomatic than `map`? Yes. Yes they are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if using a `dict` would be simpler:

```
self.models = {}
for i, key in enumerate(df,index):
        try:
            a = dfa[i].astype(float)
            setattr(self.models, key, a)
            self.models[key] = a
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

and

```
np.array([v[i] for v in self.models.values()])
```

I prefer the expressiveness of a list comprehension over that of `map`.